# How do I get documentation lookup for non-core libraries in Intellij?

Tags: documentation, intellij-idea

I have my JDK documentation path set so that I can hit Cntrl J (osx) to get 'quick documentation lookup' for core java libraries. If I try with non-core libraries like Spring or Hibernate, I only get the method signature. How do I go about getting the documentation for these libraries too?

Answer (score 2):

[Attach documentation directory](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/libraries-global-libraries-and-the-configure-library-dialog.html) or specify external documentation URL, or attach sources.

Comment: And, if you use Maven integration, and the sources are published in the repo, IDEA can automatically download them all and index them. You need the sources attached to be able to see the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven, you can use the Maven goal :

`mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc` .

This [goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) resolves the project dependencies from the repository. The [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html#classifier) specify to look for javadocs. All documentation will be downloaded inside your maven local repository, generally `~/.m2` .

After that, IntelliJ is able to find all javadoc for Spring, Hibernate, if not, check your settings inside Project Structure.